# Group parameter (set?) requiring one of the parameters

Tags: powershell, parameters

I'm trying to set up parameters where one of three set of parameters are required and include an integer followed by a colon;

```
-year:n  
-month:n  
-day:n
```

Can't quite wrap my head around parameter sets via Microsoft Docs and need help setting this up, please.

In the end the parameter will be used for Robocopy's `MinAge` parameter where if `-month:2` is used, I'll strip out the `2`, multiply by `30.4167` (average day in month) and insert `/MinAge:60.8334` as the Robocopy parameter.  I have the last part down, just not the parameter part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this can explain a bit. The function below uses three parameters, all having a different parmeter set name.

```
function Get-MinAge {
    [CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName = 'ByDays')]
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ParameterSetName = 'ByYears', Position = 0)]
        [int]$Years,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ParameterSetName = 'ByMonths', Position = 0)]
        [int]$Months,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ParameterSetName = 'ByDays', Position = 0)]
        [int]$Days
    )

    switch ($PSCmdlet.ParameterSetName) {
        'ByYears'  { $minage = $Years * 365.2422 ; break}  # average year length
        'ByMonths' { $minage = $Months * 30.4167 ; break } # average month length
        'ByDays'   { $minage = $Days }
    }
    # return the parameter for robocopy
    # wrapping inside quotes makes sure your Windows locale does not change the decimal point
    '/MinAge:{0}' -f "$minage"
}
```

Using this within the ISE editor will allow for only one of the three parameters.
The function also has a `DefaultParameterSetName`, meaning that if you dont specify the parameter name, the defauld set is used (in this case the 'ByDays' set).

Use it like so:

> ```
> Get-MinAge -Years 2   --> "/MinAge:730.4844"
> Get-MinAge -Months 2  --> "/MinAge:60.8334"
> Get-MinAge -Days 2    --> "/MinAge:2"
> Get-MinAge 2          --> "/MinAge:2"
> ```

Hope that helps

Comment: @Theo  Tremendously!!  Thank you.  Is it possible to have multiple defaultparametersetname though?  I have other parameters as well and current default is *.*, which I'm sure I could just remove for my purposes but just thought I'd ask anyway.