# Combining parameter sets

Tags: powershell, parameters

This is somewhat related to a question I asked earlier; [Group parameter (set?) requiring one of the parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58769708/group-parameter-set-requiring-one-of-the-parameters/58770075#58770075)

I have a set of 5 parameters; Years, Months, Days, Path, Input. I'm looking to combine parameter sets so that I can have the following combinations;

Years & (Path or Input)
Months & (Path or Input)
Days & (Path or Input)

Path is a typed path and Input is a pointer to a file, either way, one of them is required.

I've tried

```
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ParameterSetName = 'Path')]
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ParameterSetName = 'Input')
    [int]$Years = '7'
```

But Path & Input are required if using Years

```
Param (
    [parameter(Position = 0, ValueFromPipeline = $True, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $True)]
    [string[]]$Filter = '*.*',
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $True, ParameterSetName = 'ByYears')]
    [int]$Years = '7',
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $True, ParameterSetName = 'ByMonths')]
    [int]$Months,
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $True, ParameterSetName = 'ByDay')]
    [int]$Days,
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ParameterSetName = 'Path')]
    [string[]]$Path,
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ParameterSetName = 'Input')]
    [string]$Input,
    [switch]$Recurse,
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
    [string]$ReportPath = $PWD
)
```

In the end I'm looking to have the possibility of only one of the combinations below;

-Years 2 -Path C:\Temp
-Years 2 -Input C:\Temp\file.txt
-Months 2 -Path C:\Temp
-Months 2 -Input C:\Temp\file.txt
-Days 2 -Path C:\Temp
-Days 2 -Input C:\Temp\file.txt

Comment: you can tell PoSh to put any given parameter in _multiple parameter sets_. [*grin*] look up the MSDocs on powershell parameter sets.

Comment: Don't use [`$input`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables#input) as a parameter or user-defined variable, it'll end badly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way of directly expressing `ParameterA and (ParameterB or ParameterC)` in ParameterSets but you *can* create two ParameterSets: `ParameterA and ParameterB` and `ParameterA and ParameterC` which does the same thing.

If you extend that to your scenario, you'll need 6 ParameterSets:

- YearsAndPath
- YearsAndInput
- MonthsAndPath
- MonthsAndInput
- DaysAndPath
- DaysAndInput

And then you just tag each parameter with the ParameterSets it needs to be used in, and your `param` block becomes something like:

```
function Invoke-Params
{

    param(
        [parameter(Position = 0, ValueFromPipeline = $True, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $True)]
        [string[]]$Filter = '*.*',

        [Parameter(Mandatory = $True, ParameterSetName = 'YearsAndPath')]
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $True, ParameterSetName = 'YearsAndInput')]
        [int]$Years = '7',

        [Parameter(Mandatory = $True, ParameterSetName = 'MonthsAndPath')]
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $True, ParameterSetName = 'MonthsAndInput')]
        [int]$Months,

        [Parameter(Mandatory = $True, ParameterSetName = 'DaysAndPath')]
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $True, ParameterSetName = 'DaysAndInput')]
        [int]$Days,

        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ParameterSetName = 'YearsAndPath')]
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ParameterSetName = 'MonthsAndPath')]
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ParameterSetName = 'DaysAndPath')]
        [string[]]$Path,

        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ParameterSetName = 'YearsAndInput')]
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ParameterSetName = 'MonthsAndInput')]
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ParameterSetName = 'DaysAndInput')]
        [string]$Input,

        [switch]$Recurse,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [string]$ReportPath = $PWD
    )

}
```

The following then work fine:

```
PS> Invoke-Params -Years 5 -Path "xxx"
PS> Invoke-Params -Years 5 -Input "xxx"
```

and these throw an exception:

```
PS> Invoke-Params -Years 5
Invoke-Params : Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters.
At line:1 char:1
+ Invoke-Params -Years 5
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Invoke-Params], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AmbiguousParameterSet,Invoke-Params

PS> Invoke-Params -Years 5 -Path "aaa" -Input "bbb"
Invoke-Params : Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters.
At line:1 char:1
+ Invoke-Params -Years 5 -Path "aaa" -Input "bbb"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Invoke-Params], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AmbiguousParameterSet,Invoke-Params
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer by [mclayton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3156906/mclayton) is correct in that you would have to use 6 parameter set names.
There are three 'time' parameters that should rule each other out and must be used together with either one of two 'path' parameters.

However, you should not use `$input` as parameter, since this is an [Automatic variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables#input) as [Mathias R. Jessen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/712649/mathias-r-jessen) already commented, and because you are setting up the `$Years` parameter with a default value, `Mandatory` should be `$false` on that one.

Because using combinations of parameter sets is always a puzzle, I would put the parameters in a more logical order (at least to me..) by first defining the two 'path' parameters and setting the `DefaultParameterSetName` to be the first of those.
By also adding `Position = 0` on that first parameter, you can call the function with just the path without having to name it.

Just play around with the function below to see what combinations are possible and what the function will use:

```
function Show-Parameters {
    [CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName = 'ByFolderYears')]
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 0, ValueFromPipeline = $true, ParameterSetName = 'ByFolderYears')]
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 0, ValueFromPipeline = $true, ParameterSetName = 'ByFolderMonths')]
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 0, ValueFromPipeline = $true, ParameterSetName = 'ByFolderDays')]
        [Alias('Path')]
        [string[]]$FolderPath,

        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ParameterSetName = 'ByFileYears')]
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ParameterSetName = 'ByFileMonths')]
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ParameterSetName = 'ByFileDays')]
        [Alias('File')]
        [string]$FilePath,

        [Parameter(Mandatory = $false, ParameterSetName = 'ByFolderYears')]
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $false, ParameterSetName = 'ByFileYears')]
        [int]$Years = 7,

        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ParameterSetName = 'ByFolderMonths')]
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ParameterSetName = 'ByFileMonths')]
        [int]$Months,

        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ParameterSetName = 'ByFolderDays')]
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ParameterSetName = 'ByFileDays')]
        [int]$Days,

        [string[]]$Filter = '*.*',
        [string]$ReportPath = $PWD,
        [switch]$Recurse
    )
    # just to show what parameter the function will use
    $paramsUsed = [ordered]@{}
    $paramSet   = $PSCmdlet.ParameterSetName

    if ($paramSet.StartsWith('ByFolder')) { $paramsUsed['FolderPath'] = $FolderPath -join '; ' }
    else {$paramsUsed['FilePath'] = $FilePath}

    if ($paramSet.EndsWith('Years')) { $paramsUsed['Years'] = $Years }
    elseif ($paramSet.EndsWith('Months')) { $paramsUsed['Months'] = $Months }
    else { $paramsUsed['Days'] = $Days }

    if ($Filter) { $paramsUsed['Filter'] = $Filter -join '; ' }
    if ($ReportPath) { $paramsUsed['ReportPath'] = $ReportPath }
    if ($Recurse) { $paramsUsed['Recurse'] = $Recurse }

    Write-Host "Using ParameterSet '$paramSet'" -ForegroundColor Cyan
    $paramsUsed
}
```

For instance

```
Show-Parameters 'D:\some\path', 'Z:\some\folder'
```

outputs

> ```
> Using ParameterSet 'ByFolderYears'
>
> Name                           Value
> ----                           -----
> FolderPath                     D:\some\path; Z:\some\folder
> Years                          7
> Filter                         *.*
> ReportPath                     C:\Users\YourName
> ```

etc.